# How can I manually trigger/start celery tasks in a django application?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a django application running with a few scheduled (periodic/crontab) celery tasks. Also I have installed django-celery in order to store results in the django database backend.

Now in django admin I can see the celery models but there is no way to manually control the tasks, which I actually need for debugging purposes.

Currently I have made some views that perform `apply_async` but surely there must be a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried triggering the `run()` method of the `TaskClass` instead of  `apply_async` method?

Comment: Why not use the `shell` ?

Comment: Run shell as other users have pointed out. python manage.py shell gives you the ability trigger celery tasks at will.

Comment: You can also call tasks like normal functions from the shell or from unittests, without the need for workers, they will just execute in the current process like a normal python function.

Comment: Using the tips i managed to trigger tasks using the shell. I post the relevant command so other developers may benefit from it. 

    $ sudo -H -u www-data bash -c "python manage.py shell"
    Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
    [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    (InteractiveConsole)
    >>> from <...>.tasks import *
    >>> task_test.run()

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is only one way to debug celery. Use `celery.contrib.rdb`. You can read more in page http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/debugging.html